# SWI-Prolog: Looking for some predicate which reduces a set in some generator set for some invariant predicate?

Tags: prolog, invariants

I am looking some predicate say `generator1_inv` which is able to convert invariant generator parameter `+Inv` (with `Inv(a) = a`) and some list +ListIn of form `[...ai ... Inv(bi)]` into some list `+ListOut` which has distinct members respect to `+Inv` and if `a` and `Inv(b)=a` are members of `+ListIn`, then `Inv(Inv(...(a))` (not `a`) is a member of `+ListOut`, where `Inv` occurs `+Order` times.

Here some examples what `generator1_inv(+ListIn, -ListOut, +Inv, +Order)` should do:

Example 1)

```
?- generator1_inv([k(a), a, k(k(a)), v, b ], ListOut, k, 1)
ListOut = [k(a), v, b]
```

Example 2)

```
?- generator1_inv([k(a), r(a), a, k(k(a)), v, b ], ListOut, k, 1)
ListOut = [k(a), r(a), v, b
```

]

Example 3)

```
?- generator1_inv([r(a), a, r(abc), d(a), k(k(a)), v, b ], ListOut, k, 1)
ListOut = [r(a), k(a), r(abc), d(a) v, b]
```

Example 4)

```
?- generator1_inv([r(a), a, r(abc), d(a), k(k(a)), v, b ], ListOut, k, 0)
ListOut = [r(a), a, r(abc), d(a) v, b]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found some solution based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73181630/swi-prolog-generalize-a-predicate-to-calcluate-the-power-of-some-function) predicate `calc_power`:

```
generator_inv(ListIn, ListOut, Inv, Order) :-
    findall(X, ( member(Y, ListIn),  
                 member(Z, ListIn), 
                 not(Y = Z), 
                 calc_power(Y, X , Inv, _),
                 calc_power(Z, X , Inv, _),
                 not(calc_power(X, _, Inv, 1))), Roots),
    findall(X, (member(Y, Roots),
                member(X, ListIn),
                calc_power(X, Y , Inv, _)), ListSub),
    findall(X, (member(Y, Roots),
                calc_power(X, Y , Inv, Order)), List1),
    subtract(ListIn, ListSub, ListBase),
    union(ListBase, List1, ListOutD),
    sort(ListOutD, ListOut).
```