# SWI-Prolog: Generalize a predicate to calcluate the power of some function

Tags: function, prolog

I want to generalize some predicate written in swi-prolog to calculate the power of some function. My predicate so far is:

```
% calculates the +Power and the +Argument of some function +Function with value +Value.
calc_power(Value, Argument, Function, Power) :-
    not(Power is 0),
    Power is Power_m1 + 1,
    Value =..[Function, Buffer],
    calc_power(Buffer, Argument, Function, Power_m1), !.
calc_power(Argument, Argument, _, 0).
```

The call `calc_power((g(a)),A,f,POW).` gives so far:

```
A = g(a),
POW = 0.
```

My generalization should also solve calls like that:

```
calc_power(A1, a, f, 3).
```

the solution should be in that special calse `A1 = f(f(f(a)))`. But for some reason it doesn't work. I get the error:

```
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

in line

```
Power is Power_m1 + 1
```

it means probably in swi prolog it is not possible to take plus with two variables. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found some solution

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

% calculates the +Power and the +Argument of some function +Function with value +Value.
calc_power(Argument, Argument, _, 0).
calc_power(Value, Argument, Function, Power) :-
    Power #\= 0,
    Power #= Power_m1 + 1,
    Value =..[Function, Buffer],
    calc_power(Buffer, Argument, Function, Power_m1).
```

Answer (score 1):

Can delay the `+ 1` operation with:

```
int_succ(I0, I1) :-
    (   nonvar(I0) ->
        integer(I0),
        I0 >= 0,
        I1 is I0 + 1
    ;   nonvar(I1) ->
        integer(I1),
        I1 >= 1,
        I0 is I1 - 1
    ;   when((nonvar(I0) ; nonvar(I1)), int_succ(I0, I1))
    ).
```

Example in swi-prolog:

```
?- int_succ(I0, I1), I1 = 7.
I0 = 6,
I1 = 7.
```

This is more flexible than https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=succ/2 , and can of course be modified to support negative numbers if desired.